# Cropper.js get actual x and y of image

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I have a problem getting the `x` and `y` coordinates. My goal is to get the `x` and `y` of a point or the whole cutout square of a given image, by that I mean that if I click on the top left corner I get the `x=0` and `y=0` coordinates, but I haven't found any properties in the object to give me that.

It seems to give me the coordinates of the whole canvas, depending on how I zoom. Does anyone know how to achieve this, even if by calculating a few properties.

[This is the cropperjs library](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/)

Thank you all.

Comment: Their demo you linked to does provide this information, doesn't it?

Comment: If you see setup section there are all properties available.